# Magento Persistent Shopping Cart disables Guest Checkout when session times out

Tags: magento, cookies, checkout, cart

My customer is using Magento 1.6.2.0 with Persistent Shopping Cart and Guest Checkout enabled. We are encountering an issue that is seemingly caused by the Persistent Shopping Cart.

The `persistent_shopping_cart` cookie times out after 2 weeks, the session after 1 hour.
If the session is timed out and and the `persistent_shopping_cart` cookie is still present, the Guest Checkout option **will not** show up. The `Log In` and `My account` links are also hidden.

I can reproduce the error easily by manually deleting the session cookie, without touching the `persistent_shopping_cart` cookie.

One suggested fix was to set the cookie lifetime of the session to two weeks as well, but that doesn't sound quite right. I was wondering if there is a better solution out there.

Comment: did you get any solution for this ? i am looking for same solution.  thanks

Comment: I have also the same issue. Any body got a solution for this?